# python import works in terminal and fails in browser - from google.cloud import storage

Tags: python, browser, import, google-cloud-platform

simple 3 line python script:

```
    print("A")
    from google.cloud import storage
    print("B")
```

1. works: in terminal session -- output is A then B
2. works: `sudo  _www 3line.py` -- output is A then B
3. > Fails: called from a php, output is "A" and then nothing. No error logs produced in apacheDev-error_log.

It seems that `from google.ANYTHING import` is just plain stopping.
Failure occurs in Chrome and FireFox.

I think the problem is related to the browser environment, which is why I first tried the `sudo` to `_www ---` just hacking. It worked, so I thought that the Mac OS bash environment was handling it right under the `_www id`. Just seems that I am unaware of something related to requirements about browsers running python imports from `google.cloud`....

Any ideas?

*testing.php* is below:

```
 $command = escapeshellcmd('/Users/admin/AJweb/3line.py');
 echo $command;
 $output = shell_exec($command);
 echo $output;
```